# Move network profiles to different network location

Tags: network, wifi, internet, geolocation

I had a little problem in the last weeks because I have to use a static IP address at my work network which caused me problems using my MacBook at home. Now I just found out that macOS offers a network location feature to store different profiles for different locations, which is exactly what I need.

So my question is: How to I move my current network profiles from my *Automatic* location to my new *Work* location. Having to recreate the profiles would not really be a solution as the network profiles are rather complex (at least in my eyes) and the chance that I mess something up  is rather high.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Best wishes,
Valentin

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Network 'Locations' can be duplicated, edited & renamed, or brand new ones added. Example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbyzX.png

Comment: Of course, much smarter would be if your workplace set up specific router profiles per user (I do that here, so every 'frequently used' machine gets specific IP address & access privileges etc) so the end user just leaves their machine on Automatic… but you can approximate it from the Mac Network prefs.